# Is it possible to bundle Perl with a macOS application?

Tags: macos, perl, cocoa, command-line

I have several Cocoa applications that use Perl frameworks to perform some actions. Apple has announced that it will remove Perl, Ruby & PHP installations from future macOS versions, so I'm looking for a solution to this problem.

Making customers install Perl manually seems like madness, so are there any ways of bundling Perl or creating an executable for macOS?

I know that this is possible on Windows, but haven't been able to find anything on the Mac.

Comment: Have you looked at Par::Packer aka [pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp)?

Comment: `pp` is probably the way to go, but note that you can build `perl` on one machine then copy it to a sufficiently similar machine. If you used [`-Duserelocatableinc`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/INSTALL#Relocatable-@INC), the directory in which it's placed on the new machine can be different than the directory in which it was placed on the original machine.

Comment: Another possibility could be to use a [homebrew formula](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out PP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slic3r uses Par::Packer to bundle and ship a clickable app.

Check out their [build script for MacOX](https://github.com/slic3r/Slic3r/blob/master/package/osx/make_dmg.sh).  They copy perl into their application bundle.  I haven't really dug into how this works, but it is pretty interesting and it works well from the end-user standpoint.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out PP!